# Get vaues from ExpressJS in Angular Universal app

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular2-universal

I'm building an Angular2 Universal app and I'm integrating [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate).

Server side I need to know the language of the user, which I could get from [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com) via `request.acceptsLanguages()` ([see docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.acceptsLanguages)).

I do correctly get these values in `server.ts` like so:

```
function ngApp(req: any, res: any) {
  let supportedLangs = req.acceptsLanguages();
  console.log('supportedLangs', supportedLangs);
  res.render('index', {
    req,
    res,
    ngModule: AppModule,
    preboot: false,
    baseUrl: '/',
    requestUrl: req.originalUrl,
    originUrl: req.hostname
  });
}
```

Then I don't know how to pass them, or access them, in my `app.node.module.ts` where I set up `ng2-translate` for the server.

Is there a way to access these values from the Angular Universal app (server side)? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those interested, the solution is to use `Zone`, and when doing so there are some things to be aware of.

First, to make sure that the TypeScript parser does not break, you need to also declare,at the top of the file in which you are using `Zone`:

```
declare var Zone: any;
```

Or I guess you may install all the typings, but I have not tested that.

Then, anywhere in the node only modules you can get the parameters passed to `res.render` in the `server.ts` file by doing this:

```
let req = Zone.current.get('req');
```

Finally, you can access any of the properties passed to `req` in `server.ts`, e.g.:

```
req.headers['user-agent'];
```

**UPDATE FOR ANGULAR 5**

As pointed out in the comments, the previous code does not work anymore. The good news is that with Angular 5 is much easier and straightforward:

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { REQUEST } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';

constructor(
    private _injector: Injector
) {
    const req = this._injector.get(REQUEST);
    // use as: req.headers['whatever-is-in-the-headers']
}
```

Comment: @kris_IV thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the answer with code that should work with Angular 5 :-)

Comment: I has a problem with Zone on SSR Angular 5. It work for me only in Browser mode. I describe complex solution for my problem hire: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48509431/2972087

Comment: I am getting this error with this solution:
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(o)[InjectionToken REQUEST]: